# Display search key word in div and display that div on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have to implement 2 things.
1) I have a search box in my page. where i can enter text to search. I want to display search term or key word in a div. something like this
[image]

right now I am displaying in textbox. How do I display in div?

```js
function showDiv() {
                document.getElementById('searchtermdiv').style.display = "";
 }
```

```html
<div>
     <div >
           @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", "", new { placeholder ="Search..." })
      </div>
      <div style="float:right;">
           <button type="submit" onclick="showDiv()">Go</button>
       </div>

</div>
```

```
<div id="searchtermdiv">
    <strong>You searched for "@Html.TextBox("searchTerm", "", new { @class = "searchcontext" })"</strong>
</div>
```

2) I need to display the div page load. At present div is displaying on button click but it is disappearing on page load.

Comment: document.getElementById('myDivId').innerHTML = '%MySearchTerm%';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a placeholder element like a div or span and update the content of that using JavaScript by reading the current value of the input.

```
<div id="searchtermdiv">
    <strong>You searched for "<span id="searchterm"></span>"</strong>
</div>
```

and

```
function showDiv()
{
    var v = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
    document.getElementById('searchterm').innerText = v;
}
```

For this to happen when the page loads, calls the same method on the onload event

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    showDiv();
}
```

If you want to hide the entire preview element when the search text is not present, you can conditionally update the visibility of that element based on the value of search text input.

```
function showDiv()
{
    var v = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
    document.getElementById('searchterm').innerText = v;
    if (v)
    {
        document.getElementById("searchtermdiv").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("searchtermdiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

**Or**

If you are using a setting the value of `ViewBag.searchTerm` in your GET action method and want to display that in the preview element, you can use the same value when rendering the preview element markup

```
<span id="searchterm">@ViewBag.searchTerm</span>
```

With this appraoch, you do not need the client side method call on the `onload` event

Comment: Thanks. Your code helped me. Sorry. I forgot to add one more thing. I need to display this whole thing <div id="searchtermdiv">
    <strong>You searched for "<span id="searchterm"></span>"</strong>
</div> only when I enter any text and click button.

Comment: You said you want it in the page load as well!

Comment: Yes. if I enter any text to search I need to display that search term on page load.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('searchTermDiv').innerHTML=        
   "You search for : " + document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
 }
```

```html
<div>
    <div id='searchTermDiv'> </div>
     <div>
           @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", "", new { placeholder ="Search..." })
      </div>
      <div style="float:right;">
           <button type="submit" onclick="showDiv()">Go</button>
       </div>

</div>
```

With this If you search for "Hot Topic" this div will add text as 
"**You search for : Hot Topic**"